# Why isn't my GUI displaying?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm using inteliJ to write a file transfer program and I'm working on the GUI right now using Swing. I've made plenty of programs in swing, but for some reason I can't figure out why my GUI isn't showing up when I run the program. Everything compiles just fine.

```
    public class stage  {

    JPanel mainContainer = new JPanel();
    JPanel window = new JPanel();
    JButton loadButton = new JButton();
    JButton saveButton = new JButton();
    JTextPane cmdOut = new JTextPane();
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu();
    JMenuItem exitButton = new JMenuItem("exit");

public void display(){
    mainContainer.setVisible(true);
    mainContainer.add(window);
    mainContainer.add(menuBar);
    menuBar.add(menu);
    menu.add(exitButton);
    window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    window.add(loadButton);
    window.add(saveButton);
    window.add(cmdOut);
    cmdOut.setText("TEST");
    window.setVisible(true);



}


}
```

Here is my main method in another class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    stage stage = new stage();

    stage.display();




}
```

Comment: You never added `mainContainer` to any sort of window.  Try sticking it in a `JFrame`.

Comment: Ahhhh damn I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking. Cheers mate.

Comment: well he's gone and commented it, before i posted my answer :(

Comment: There is no "window" based classed. Have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) fo rmore details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you put your main panel into a JFrame, so that your JFrame will contain your main panel, and your main panel hold everything else?